# dask dataframes -time series partitions

Tags: pandas, dask

I have a timeseries pandas dataframe that I want to partition by month and year.  My thought was to get a list of datetimes that would serve as the index but the break doesnt happen at the start 0:00 at the first of the month..

```
monthly_partitons=np.unique(df.index.values.astype('datetime64[M]')).tolist()
da=dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
```

how do I set the index to start at each month?  I tried `npartitions=len(monthly_partitions)` but I realize that is wrong as the it may not partition on the date at start time.  how should one ensure it partiitons on the first date of the month?

**UPDATE:**

using `da=da.repartition(freq='1M')`  resampled the data from 10 minutes data to 1 minute data see below

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
Open    High    Low Close   Vol OI  VI  
npartitions=5037050                             
2008-05-04 18:00:00 float64 float64 float64 float64 int64   int64   float64 int32
2008-05-04 18:01:00 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2017-12-01 16:49:00 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2017-12-01 16:50:00 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
Dask Name: repartition-merge, 10074101 tasks
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the code to reproduce the problem

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import dask as dsk
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

ts=pd.date_range("2015-01-01 00:00", " 2015-05-01 23:50", freq="10min")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(ts),4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index=ts)
ddf=dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1)
ddf=ddf.repartition(freq='1M')
ddf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is already indexed by time you should be able to use the [repartition method](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.repartition) to accomplish this.

```
df = df.repartition(freq='1M')
```

#### Edit after MCVE above

(thanks for adding the minimal and complete example!)

Interesting, this looks like a bug, either in pandas or dask.  I assumed that `'1M'` would mean one month, (as it does in `pd.date_range`)

```
In [12]: pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-15', freq='1M')
Out[12]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-30',
               '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31',
               '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

And yet, when passed to `pd.Timedelta`, it means one minute

```
In [13]: pd.Timedelta('1M')
Out[13]: Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')

In [14]: pd.Timedelta('1m')
Out[14]: Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')
```

So it's hanging because it's trying to make around 43200 more partitions than you intended :)

We should file a bug report for this (do you have any interest in doing this?).  A short term workaround would be to specify divisions yourself explicitly.

```
In [17]: divisions = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-05-01', freq='1M').tolist
    ...: ()
    ...: divisions[0] = ddf.divisions[0]
    ...: divisions[-1] = ddf.divisions[-1]
    ...: ddf.repartition(divisions=divisions)
    ...: 
Out[17]: 
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                         A      B      C      D
npartitions=3                                  
2015-01-01 00:00:00  int64  int64  int64  int64
2015-02-28 00:00:00    ...    ...    ...    ...
2015-03-31 00:00:00    ...    ...    ...    ...
2015-05-01 23:50:00    ...    ...    ...    ...
Dask Name: repartition-merge, 7 tasks
```

Comment: I tried that method it hangs up Requiring an interrupt to stop the process. I didn’t have that problem when I  set the number of partitions.  Well the partitions were in the wrong place, I was still able to pass the DataFrame and process

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE, that makes it much easier to identify and resolved.  Answered in an edit.

Comment: thanks for the help as I suspected it was in timedelta

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to partition by the first day of each month then use the following:

```
ddf.repartition(freq='MS')
```

where `MS` means *month start*.  Information on more `DateOffset` objects can be found in the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)